# Grammar and syntax of typedef in C language

Tags: c, typedef

I have a problem with the typedef keywords in C language.

In my program, I use the following codes:

```
typedef int* a[10];

int main(){
 int a[10];
}
```

they work well. But why there are no conflicts between a variable and a type sharing the same name a?

Regards.

Comment: Cool question - I've never really considered this. The type you define is damn weird though, I hope it's only for demonstration purposes :-)

Comment: You're right, I don't want my code as hard to read as a puzzle, either. :-)

Comment: Wow, GCC is even okay with "a a;" (as long as it's in main, not global)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [msdn C language reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x7sfztk(VS.80).aspx):

> Typedef names share the name space with ordinary identifiers (see [Name Spaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx5ywe6y(v=VS.80).aspx) for more information). Therefore, a program can have a typedef name and a local-scope identifier by the same name.

Comment: Curious quote. Reading it quickly it feels like an oxymoron. If they share a namespace, how could they have the same name? Is this because of the *local-scope*?

Comment: Hmm... the "Name Spaces" link you point to says: "Typedef names cannot be used as identifiers in the same scope. "

Comment: @sbi: the compiler forgives even if `int a[10]` is declared in the global scope together with the typedef

Comment: @Eli Bendersky: GCC 4.4.1 doesn't show much forgiveness and refuses to compile the source code if you put the variable declaration into the same scope as the typedef (i.e. moving the variable declaration to global scope or the typedef into main())

Answer (score 6):

The C standard says (Section 6.2.1 - Scopes of identifiers):

> An identifier can denote an object; a
>   function; a tag or a member of a
>   structure, union, or enumeration; a
>   typedef name; a label name; a macro
>   name; or a macro parameter. The same
>   identifier can denote different
>   entities at different points in the
>   program.

K&R2 say (A.11.1 - Lexical Scope)

> Identifiers fall into several name
>   spaces that do not interfere with one
>   another; the same identifier may be
>   used for different purposes, even in
>   the same scope, if the uses are in
>   different name spaces. These classes
>   are: objects, functions, typedef
>   names, and enum constants; labels;
>   tags of structures or unions, and
>   enumerations; and members of each
>   structure or union individually.

I must admit this confuses me. Reading the second quote it appears that variable names and `typedef`-ed types *should* clash.

Comment: But I am still not very clear how can "a" denoting different entities coexists in the preceeding codes. Could you give me further explanation, please? Thanks.

Comment: @Neil: I read the punctuation differently. Seems like objects, functions, typedef names and enum constants are one class. Next (after a semicolon) labels, next tags, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Variables and typedefs occupy the *same* namespace, and can *not* share names with other identifiers in exactly the same scope.

However your second `a` is inside `main`, and scope rules apply: the second `a` overrides the first.

You can do the same thing with just plain variables:

```
int a;

int main() {
    int a;
}
```

You'll notice that if you move the variable declaration outside main, the program won't compile.